Asian movie about killing cops as a game for points
I've seen the movie a few years ago so I believe it's from 2000-2010, in color.
The movie is about a gang of kids (around the age of 16-18) who have rich parents and are making a video game of the people they kill. They kill for sport as it is a game to them. They mostly kill cops I believe. Killing a cop awards X amount of points. They have tons of weapons, all kind of weapons (I think even a bazooka). I'm 100% sure they are Asian actors
Scene's that I remember:

Some cops are half dead hanging on ropes from the ceiling and the main-character cop has to try and save them in a warehouse, the gang are looking down on the main-character cop from above.
The gang is standing in the middle of the street waiting for cops and when the cops arrive they open fire. I believe 1 person of the gang gets hit in the shoulder. They start counting how many kills they get for points. I believe one shouts something about ' that's extra points '.

What I'm unsure of:

I believe the main-character cop might be a bit of an alcohol drinker, yet I'm not 100% sure of it.
The gang sometimes play with BMX & Rollerblades 
I believe the movie takes place in China or Japan
I might have seen the movie in english dubbed.


This sounds like New Police Story from 2004 with Jackie Chan.

A hero cop accidentally leads his team into a trap from which he is the only survivor. Drowning his guilt in booze, he is eventually assigned a new younger partner who turns out to have his own secrets.

The villains are a gang of spoiled rich kids who kill cops for sport and make a video game out of it. The scene where they're all hanging from the ceiling is there too, and appears in the trailer:




wow how did you find it so fast O.o thanks!

I just know the film ;) Glad you found it (and nice question).

yea I'll accept it as answer when I can. I watched it as a kid, loveed it only never saw the ending, thunder & lightning cut power back then haha
